# Beginner: How to make round corners?

Tags: bevel

Hello and thanks for reading!

I am a beginner and succeeded drawing an outline of a chair with a bezier curve like so:

[image]

I then converted this curve into a mesh and extruded it like so:

[image]

So now I got the perfect shape when looking from the side. But now I fail when shaping it from the front. While the edges drawn with the curve are nice and smooth, the extrusion creates very sharp edges like so:

[image]

I would like to make them roundand tried with bevel, I tried to inset the face, but I cannot find a way to get some rounded edges. Could anyone point me to the right direction, plese? Thank you so much!

Comment: Try using smooth tool in sculpting.

Comment: It should work with bevel, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Did you try to bevel in _Edit Mode_ or with the _Bevel_ modifier? How clean is the geometry? Have you applied the scale? PS: don't use the _Smooth_ tool in _Sculpt Mode_ for a simple regular bevel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to separate your levels of detail, and the tasks to create them.

The coarse level of detail would be dealt with by your curve. It's the shape the board would be cut to in a joinery..

[image]

... keeping the control points to a minimum to capture the shape, leaving fine corners sharp. (Think 'band-saw'.)

And then, *after* conversion to mesh, solidifying, deal with smoothing out the sharp corners.. (The 'sanding' stage.) :

[image]

.. if you did that with, say, *Solidify* and *Bevel* modifiers, you leave open the option of varying the smoothing-width by edge bevel weight, if you really need to.

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! I succeeded! Great! Thaank you so much! I tried bevelling with CTRL-B in edit mode, but now since I use the modifier it works! Thanks!